# Writing a CSV file - adding a prefix to the column names

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Writing a collection in a CSV file I want to add a property value as prefix to the column names. 
Is there a way to configure the mapper to write the column names with a property value as we have in the following example.

csv file

Property, Id, 123_Property1,123_Property2, Id, 456_Property1, 456_Property2

Title, 123, John, Smith, 456, Helen, Thomson

```
public class MyClass
    {
      public string Property {get; set;}
      public List<MyCustom> MyCustoms {get; set;}
    }

   public class MyCustom 
        {
           public string Id {get; set;}
           public string Property2 {get; set;}
           public string Property3 {get; set;}
         }

 public class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
 {
   public MyClassMap(){
   this.Map(m => m.Property).Name("Property"); 
(?)this.Map(m => m.MyCustoms).Name("IdVALUE ...");
  }
```

Comment: You should explain more and add some examples.  As is it is not clear and even looks a little like you are confused what the map does

Comment: I think `MyClass` is supposed to have a property that is something like `public List<Custom> MyCustom { get; set; }`.  The problem is your code is not valid code and makes it confusing as to what you are trying to do.  I think you are trying to flatten that list out across the CSV file.  Could one `MyClass` have a list of 5 `Custom` and another have a list of 20 `Custom`?  Could there be 100 different `Custom.Id` values?  If these are not things you will know ahead of time, I don't think you can do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DavidSpecht thank you for your answer. To solve this problem in the MyClassMap constructor I had to inject the model for which I want to generate the Csv file.

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp thank you for you answer. Unfortunately, trying to correct the format of  my code section I missed up the consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do can be done, but it makes some assumptions and can be easily broken.  Ultimately you should rethink your CSV structure. This solution manually writes the header record and uses a custom `TypeConverter` to print out each `MyCustom` class.

Assumptions

- Every `MyClass` will have the same number of `MyCustom` and the ids will match between each `MyClass` record.
- <del>MyCustom Id's will print out in the same order each time.</del> (Update: Added `OrderBy` to fix this issue.)

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{    
    var records = new List<MyClass> {
        new MyClass {
            Property = "Title",
            MyCustoms = new List<MyCustom> {
                new MyCustom { Id = "123", Property1 = "John", Property2 = "Smith" },
                new MyCustom { Id = "456", Property1 = "Helen", Property2 = "Thomson"}
            }
        },
        new MyClass {
            Property = "AnotherProperty",
            MyCustoms = new List<MyCustom> {
                new MyCustom { Id = "123", Property1 = "Another11", Property2 = "Another12" },
                new MyCustom { Id = "456", Property1 = "Another21", Property2 = "Another22"}
            }
        }
    };

    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out))
    {
        csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<List<MyCustom>>(new MyTypeConverter());
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;

        // Get all of the ids from the first record.
        var ids = records[0].MyCustoms.OrderBy(m => m.Id).Select(m => m.Id).ToList();

        csv.WriteField("Property");

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            csv.WriteField("Id");
            csv.WriteField($"{id}_Property1");
            csv.WriteField($"{id}_Property2");
        }

        csv.NextRecord();

        csv.WriteRecords(records);                
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}


public class MyClass
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public List<MyCustom> MyCustoms {get;set;}
}

public class MyCustom
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

private class MyTypeConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var list = ((List<MyCustom>)value).OrderBy(m => m.Id).ToList();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            row.WriteField(item.Id);
            row.WriteField(item.Property1);
            row.WriteField(item.Property2);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you and I really appreciate your help. I understand that in this case we have some assumptions but that was the requirement that I received.